# Как стилизовать чекбокс?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вот такая форма, как стилизовать её чекбокс?

```html
<form>
  <label for="check-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="4л">
    <span>4л</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Пробовал стилизовать вот так, но не получается:

```css
.box1 input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.box1 label:before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.box1 input[type=checkbox]:checked + .box1 label:before {
  content: "\2713";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: А как Вы попробовали стилизовать? Первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу `Стилизация чекбоксов` - http://dimox.name/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-using-css-only/

Comment: Дописал в вопросе код, как пробовал... не получилось.

Comment: @Александр это iCheck?

Comment: Нет, я не юзал плагины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + span:before {
  content: "\2715";
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="check-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="4л">
    <span>4л</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

А как вам такой чекбокс?

```css
input {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
input:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -0.125rem;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 1rem;
 height: 1rem;
 border: 2px solid #d5d5d5;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input:checked:before {
 height: .5rem;
 border-color: #339933;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
input:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -0.125rem;
 left: 0;
 width: 1.1rem;
 height: 1.1rem;
 background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="check-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="4л">
    <span>4л</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + span, input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

input[type="radio"] + span {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  border-radius: .25em;
}

input:checked + span {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<label><input type=radio name=r><span></span></label>
<label><input type=radio name=r><span></span></label>
<label><input type=radio name=r><span></span></label>
<label><input type=radio name=r><span></span></label>
<br>
<label><input type=checkbox name=c><span></span></label>
<label><input type=checkbox name=c><span></span></label>
<label><input type=checkbox name=c><span></span></label>
<label><input type=checkbox name=c><span></span></label>
```