# Как правильно вывести чекбокс?

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго времени суток !

Есть форма в которой есть чекбокс, суть работы формы проста, она отправляет значение чекбокса в базу данных.
Состояние чекбокса меняет js скрипт, который при нажатии меняет класс чекбокса на `checked` и изменяет значение в `input`.

JS Код:

```
function superCheckbox(event, scope) {
    document.getElementById('tagsOn').checked = true
    if (event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') return
    if (scope.classList.contains('Checkbox--checked')) {
        scope.classList.remove('Checkbox--checked')
        document.getElementById('tagsOn').value = '0'
    } else {
        scope.classList.add('Checkbox--checked')
        document.getElementById('tagsOn').value = '1'
    }
}
```

Моя реализация отображения чекбокса:

```
    <?php if ($view_tagsOn['tagsOn'] == false): ?>
    <label onclick=" superCheckbox(event, this) " class="Checkbox  ">
    <?php else: ?>
    <label onclick=" superCheckbox(event, this) " class="Checkbox Checkbox--checked ">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <span class="circle">
            <span class="in-circle"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tagsOn" name="tagsOn" value=" <?php echo $view_tagsOn['tagsOn']; ?> ">
        <div class="Input__label">Включены/Отключены</div>
    </label>
```

Но у неё есть баг, если отправить форму через кнопку не трогая чекбокс, то состояние чекбокса и значение в БД поменяются произвольно.


Вопрос:

Как правильно реализовать отображение чекбокса в форме (данные берутся из БД) ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554555/178988 - вот так надо делать, а не городить такую муть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как будет меняться value(true/false) ?

Comment: `checked` будет меняться, соответственно при false он тебе `value` вообще не пришлёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Как правильно вывести чекбокс?

---

Чтобы не городить муть, как выразился [Qwertiy♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), я сделал так:

Заменил чекбокс на кнопку.

```
<?php if ($view_tagsOn['tagsOn'] == false): ?> 
<button type="submit" name="tagsOn" id="tagsOn" class="button" value="1"  >Включить тэги</button>
<?php else: ?>
<button type="submit" name="tagsOn" id="tagsOn" class="button secondary" value="0" ><span class="tick"></span>Выключить тэги</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

А в обработчике формы поставил проверку на то, какая кнопка была нажата:

```
if(isset($_POST['tagsOn']))
{
    /*
        Тут просиходит подготовленный запрос UPDATE, для смены значения кнопки
    */
    header("Location: /"); // Делаем редирект обратно к форме
}
```

Таким образом я избавился от произвольной смены значения в бд при простом сохранении формы.