# Как поменять цвет input type radio

Tags: html, css, input, radio

Предположим, есть такой код, как в нем сделать ободку кнопки синей и при нажатии в центре тоже синий был.

```css
input[type='radio'],
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='radio'] {
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer1" value="yes">
  <label for="answer1">&nbsp&nbspДа</label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer2" value="no">
  <label for="answer2">&nbsp&nbspНет</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Никак, делайте кастомный radio через псевдоелемент или просто елемент.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554555/178988

Comment: да, такой способ тоже вижу первый раз, попробую применить, благодарю за идею!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разве что только кастомный, с помощью псевдоэлементов:

```css
input[type='radio'],
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  position: relative;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}

input[type='radio']::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}

input[type='radio']:checked::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer1" value="yes">
  <label for="answer1">&nbsp&nbspДа</label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="answer2" value="no">
  <label for="answer2">&nbsp&nbspНет</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Какие я уже только не делал и не видел, но такой вижу впервые!